# SendDlgItemMessage CB_GETLBTEXT on DropDownList combo returns a single letter

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, visual-studio-2017, sendmessage

I'm using the following code to retrieve the text of a combo dropdown list item.

```
char strText[255];
SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDC_COMBO_VOICES, CB_GETLBTEXT,0, (LPARAM)strText);
std::string sTest = (strText);
```

I expected a longer string, but both strText and sTest only contain a single letter.
It is in fact that first letter of the combobox item text, so I can't be completely wrong, but I still don't get it right.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are building for Unicode?  Also what is the return value of the function?

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes. I'm building for Unicode. Return value is 32.

Comment: You need to pass a wide char array in.  `wchar_t strText[255];`. Because you are getting UTF-16 back in your char array.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you very much! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you tick the 'Has Strings' checkbox in the Combo Box's properties